# Neomodel / py2neo - 'NodeMeta' object is not iterable

Tags: django, neo4j, neomodel

I am new to Neomodel and Neo4J.  I am running a remote Neo4J server on Amazon Ec2, developing locally and running into issues when trying to access the project via the browser.

When attempting to access the project via my browser, I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /
'NodeMeta' object is not iterable
```

Here is my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from app.admin import BaseAppAdmin
from .nodes import TwitterPost

class TweetAdmin(BaseAppAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('postId', 'text')
    search_fields = ('text',)

admin.site.register(TwitterPost, TweetAdmin)
```

I have been reading through the docs in py2neo on batch read/write functionality, but I am not sure how to implement this. ( http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/batches/#py2neo.neo4j.ReadBatch )

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am presuming TwitterPost is a StructuredNode definition? It looks like your trying to register it with django admin however neomodel nodes don't integrate with django admin (yet) but patches are most welcome :-)

Rob

Comment: Hi Rob, yes TwitterPost is a structured node I am trying to incorporate into the Django admin.  I will most definitely work on some patches and submit if I come up with something decent.  Am I on the right track with the link below?  Also, does Neomodel work with Django class based views and html templates?  Apologies if these are newbie questions :)   Here is the referenced link: http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/batches/#py2neo.neo4j.ReadBatch

Comment: Hey, at present neomodel doesn't play nice with ReadBatch I am working on it though. Yes it will work with class based views in django it doesn't currently support the special views like ListView etc though.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the update.  I have been using Neomodel in a project and I am really loving it.  Once I realized that I could pass cypher queries straight to the db ( like this http://neomodel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cypher.html#stand-alone ) that made things a lot easier.  Thanks for the great project!